# wp_nav_menu - Collapse with PHP

Tags: menus, walker

How can wp_nav_menu be used to collapse and expand elements with PHP? Some walker function? Plugin maybe?

**What it looks like in wp-admin menus**

```
About
    Customers
    Cases
Contact
    Contact us
    Contact someone else
```

**On the front page - When I have not selected anything it should look like this**

```
About
Contact
```

**When I selected About it should look like this**

```
About
    Customers
    Cases
Contact
```

**When I selected Customers it should look like this**

```
About
Contact
    Contact us
    Contact someone else
```

Comment: I Googled but I have found something now. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working solution. It's a plugin called [Advanced Menu Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-menu-widget/). I had to add a widget area into my theme but I can live with that, for now. It works!